# Remove lines in dataframe using a list in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

It's a generic question about filtering a pandas dataframe using a list. The problem is the following:

- I have a pandas dataframe `df` with a column `field`
- I have a list of banned fields, for example `ban_field=['field1','field2','field3']`
- All elements of `ban_field` appear in `df.field`

For the moment, to retrieve the dataframe without the banned field, I proceed as follows:

```
for f in ban_field:
    df = df[df.field!=f]
```

Is there a more pythonic way to proceed (in one line?)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Method #1: use `isin` and a boolean array selector:

```
In [47]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [2]*10, "field": range(10)})

In [48]: ban_field = [3,4,6,7,8]

In [49]: df[~df.field.isin(ban_field)]
Out[49]: 
   a  field
0  2      0
1  2      1
2  2      2
5  2      5
9  2      9

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

Method #2: use `query`:

```
In [51]: df.query("field not in @ban_field")
Out[51]: 
   a  field
0  2      0
1  2      1
2  2      2
5  2      5
9  2      9

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove it by using the `isin` function and the negation (`~`) operator.

```
df[~df.field.isin(ban_field)]
```